# Segmentation fault when return a integer pointer or base address of the array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a program in [c](/questions/tagged/c) and I encountered an error message:

```
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
```

At that time I ran that program using [dev-c++](/questions/tagged/dev-c%2b%2b) on my system then the program ran successfully until it returned:

```
[Warning] function returns address of local variable [enabled by default]
```

I am not able to understand what is happening.

Here's my program:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int* getRecord(int s_size, int* s, int *result_size){
    int i = 0, heigh = s[0], low = s[0], heigh_count = 0, low_count = 0, a[2];
    for(i = 1; i < s_size; i++){
        if(s[i] > heigh){
            heigh_count++;
            heigh = s[i];
        }
        if(s[i] < low){
            low_count++;
            low = s[i];
        }
    }
    *result_size = 2;
    a[0] = heigh_count;
    a[1] = low_count;
    return a;
}

int main() {
    int n; 
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int *s = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    for(int s_i = 0; s_i < n; s_i++){
       scanf("%d",&s[s_i]);
    }
    int result_size;
    int* result = getRecord(n, s, &result_size);
    for(int i = 0; i < result_size; i++) {
        if (i) {
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("%d", result[i]);
    }
    puts("");
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
9

10 5 20 20 4 5 2 25 1
```

**Output**

```
2 4
```

**Error log**

```
GDB trace:
Reading symbols from solution...done.
[New LWP 17778]
Core was generated by `solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  0x000000000040065d in printf (__fmt=0x4008a7 "%d")
    at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:104
104   return __printf_chk (__USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1, __fmt, __va_arg_pack ());
#0  0x000000000040065d in printf (__fmt=0x4008a7 "%d")
    at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:104
#1  main () at solution.c:41
```

Comment: Hmm..returning the address of an automatic local variable...what did you expect?

Comment: i want to return integer point from the function int* getRecord(int s_size, int* s, int *result_size), we know array name is base address, that by i am returning a.

Comment: Hi sourav ghosh, can you tell me where i am wrong .....

Comment: @JITENDRAKUSHVAHA read the linked duplicate. quick summary, `a` has automatic storage (default for variables in function scope), so it *doesn't exist any more* as soon as the function is left.

Comment: same as @FelixPalmen said, do read the lined question and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning

> function returns address of local variable

pretty much says it all. You can't return array `a` as an `int*`.

`a` is destroyed when `getRecord()` returns so you are left with `result` holding a pointer to invalid data, and you will get a segmentation fault when trying to access `result[i]`.

If you put `a` on the heap with `malloc`, you will probably be fine, but there is still a weird mixture of pointers and arrays here.

Comment: thank you so much Mark Ch for clearing my doubt.....